# Pass parameter with navigateForward angular 7

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass a parameter on the route but it arrives at as undefined.
On the login screen I call through the NavController tabs, but in the ActivatedRoute tabs the route arrives as undefined.

```
export class TabsPage {
  logado = false;
  id=0;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private route: ActivatedRoute) 
  { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params["id"];
    });

    if(this.id == undefined || this.id == null || this.id == NaN || this.id < 1){
      this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/login');
      this.logado = false;
    }else{
      this.logado = true;
      this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/home');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to paste the whole code here but I can not get it

Answer (score 0):

Move your logic into your queryParams subscription so it only runs once the id is set:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.id = params["id"];

    if (this.id == undefined || this.id == null || this.id == NaN || this.id < 1) {
      this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/login');
      this.logado = false;
    } else {
      this.logado = true;
      this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/home');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Essa é chamada da page. Porem ela sempre chega undefined e eu nao consigo descobrir porque ate entao sera passada sempre com valor >>> if(res.json() != null){
          let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            queryParams: {
              id : res.json()
            }
          }
          this.id = parseInt(res.json());
          this.router.navigate(['/tabs'], navigationExtras );